# How to remove constraint based on columns from oracle database?

Tags: oracle, constraints

Is there is a way to remove a constraint (unique index) based on columns name?

What I would like to do is to remove a constraint where columna name is name, and name_type.

`ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT NAME_OF_CONSTRAINT;`

I don't have a name so I would like to do it this way...

`ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT **WHERE COLUMN = col1 AND column = col2**`

Any syntax to do something like this on a constraint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't think this was possible with a single statement, but it turns out it is, as shown [in the examples in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#i2133199):

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP UNIQUE(col1, col2);
```

A complete example:
    ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD UNIQUE (col1, col2);

```
Table my_table altered.

SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME, INDEX_NAME
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE';

CONSTRAINT_NAME                INDEX_NAME                    
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SYS_C0092455                   SYS_C0092455                   

ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP UNIQUE(col1, col2);

Table my_table altered.

SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME, INDEX_NAME
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE';

no rows selected
```

An alternative approach is to query the `USER_CONSTRAINTS` and `USER_CONS_COLUMNS` views to find the matching constraint name - presumably system-generated or you would already know it - and then use that name. If you need to do this as a script then you could query in a PL/SQL block, and plug the found constraint name into a dynamic `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do a `SELECT * FROM USER_CONS_COLUMNS` or `ALL_CONS_COLUMNS`. This will give you the constraint name for the owner, table and column combination.
2. Out of the multiple rows returned for a column name, use the constraint names as necessary in the `ALTER TABLE ... DROP CONSTRAINT...` syntax.
3. Use dynamic sql to do it for all rows in a loop if you are absolutely sure that you can drop all of them.

This will give you an extra layer of protection so that you don't accidentally drop a constraint that was needed.