# how to find the constraint name of a column from table and drop it with a single query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I need to find the constraint name of a column  and I need to delete it  with a single select statement  .
if not possible then what is the alternative way

I need to give this query to another person so that when he run the query it will automatically find the constraint name for the column for a particular table and then delete it .. without hard coded anything

Comment: What kind of constraint? [This might save you a step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28545284/266304)?

Comment: not null constraint

Comment: Don't you just want to do `alter table .. column ... null` then? You shouldn't need to know the system-generated name for that.

Comment: I was asking  how to drop the constraint  without knowing the name

Comment: You don't need to know the name, that's what I was saying. [Like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=194e3bba8831c47d28be353b498a8e47). You just need the table and column name; which you would have to know anyway to look up the name. If you can't do that, what am I missing?

Comment: This is not possible with single statement nut check this-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544816/how-to-remove-constraint-based-on-columns-from-oracle-database?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example - a test table, with `NOT NULL` constraint to be dropped.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test
  2  (
  3     id    NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  4     name  VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,            --> this constraint should be dropped
  5     sex   VARCHAR2 (1) CHECK (sex IN ('Y', 'N'))
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> SELECT table_name, column_name, constraint_name
  2    FROM user_cons_columns
  3   WHERE table_name = 'TEST';

TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAM CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------ ---------- ------------------------------
TEST                           NAME       SYS_C0069006     --> this one
TEST                           SEX        SYS_C0069007
TEST                           ID         SYS_C0069008

SQL>
```

A function (because of `LONG` datatype for `USER_CONSTRAINTS.SEARCH_CONDITION`, so that we could check whether it is the `NOT NULL` one):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sc (par_constraint_name IN VARCHAR2)
  2     RETURN VARCHAR2
  3  IS
  4     l_search_condition  user_constraints.search_condition%TYPE;
  5  BEGIN
  6     SELECT search_condition
  7       INTO l_search_condition
  8       FROM user_constraints
  9      WHERE constraint_name = par_constraint_name;
 10
 11     RETURN l_search_condition;
 12  END;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

A procedure which will accept table name and column name; if there's the `NOT NULL` constraint on it, it'll be dropped. Otherwise, nothing will happen:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_dropcon (par_table_name   IN VARCHAR2,
  2                                         par_column_name  IN VARCHAR2)
  3  IS
  4     l_con  user_cons_columns.constraint_name%TYPE;
  5  BEGIN
  6     SELECT a.constraint_name
  7       INTO l_con
  8       FROM user_constraints a
  9            JOIN user_cons_columns b ON b.constraint_name = a.constraint_name
 10      WHERE     a.table_name = UPPER (par_table_name)
 11            AND b.column_name = UPPER (par_column_name)
 12            AND INSTR (UPPER (f_sc (a.constraint_name)), 'IS NOT NULL') > 0;
 13
 14     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
 15           'alter table '
 16        || DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name (par_table_name)
 17        || ' drop constraint '
 18        || l_con;
 19  EXCEPTION
 20     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
 21     THEN
 22        -- There's no NOT NULL constraint on that column
 23        NULL;
 24  END;
 25  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> EXEC p_dropcon('test', 'name');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT table_name, column_name, constraint_name
  2    FROM user_cons_columns
  3   WHERE table_name = 'TEST';

TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAM CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------ ---------- ------------------------------
TEST                           SEX        SYS_C0069007
TEST                           ID         SYS_C0069008
```

OK; constraint on the `NAME` column was dropped. How about `ID`?

```
SQL> EXEC p_dropcon('test', 'id');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT table_name, column_name, constraint_name
  2    FROM user_cons_columns
  3   WHERE table_name = 'TEST';

TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAM CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------ ---------- ------------------------------
TEST                           SEX        SYS_C0069007
TEST                           ID         SYS_C0069008

SQL>
```

Nothing happened, as expected.

---

**However** (although not very likely to happen), if you've created your own check constraint which contains the search string, `IS NOT NULL`, e.g.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test
  2  (
  3     id    NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  4     name  VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,
  5     sex   VARCHAR2 (1) CHECK (sex IN ('IS NOT NULL'))     --> this
  6  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

and run the same procedure on that column, the constraint will be dropped although it isn't what you wanted:

```
SQL> SELECT table_name, column_name, constraint_name
  2    FROM user_cons_columns
  3   WHERE table_name = 'TEST';

TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAM CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------ ---------- ------------------------------
TEST                           NAME       SYS_C0069012
TEST                           SEX        SYS_C0069013
TEST                           ID         SYS_C0069014

SQL> EXEC p_dropcon('test', 'sex');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT table_name, column_name, constraint_name
  2    FROM user_cons_columns
  3   WHERE table_name = 'TEST';

TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAM CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------ ---------- ------------------------------
TEST                           NAME       SYS_C0069012
TEST                           ID         SYS_C0069014

SQL>
```

---

Conclusion: you shouldn't be dropping constraints blindly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply provide the following query in one of the .sql scripts to the customer where the customer just need to change the table name.

You can also use a procedure or another known method of SQL execution which can execute the following code:

```
BEGIN
    FOR I IN (
        SELECT
            TABLE_NAME,
            COLUMN_NAME,
            NULLABLE
        FROM
            USER_TAB_COLUMNS
        WHERE
            TABLE_NAME = 'TEST'
            AND NULLABLE = 'N'
    ) LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '
                          || I.TABLE_NAME
                          || ' MODIFY '
                          || I.COLUMN_NAME
                          || ' NULL ';
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

You can see the [db<>fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=32b63f0b6184c524da25419dc683d16d).

Cheers!!